# TextBox LostFocus event occurs too often

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I have an application in Silverlight and WPF. The error just happens in Silverlight, but same code is used in WPF.

In my application, there is a `RibbonBar`, with several `RibbonGroups`. In each `RibbonGroup` there are at least one `RibbonButton`. One of those `RibbonGroups` also contains four `TextBox`.

Every `TextBox` has its own `OnLostFocus`-Handler. When I leave a `TextBox` the related Handler is raised.

Now, (1) I click into one of those TextBoxes and (2) then click a RibbonButton, OnLostFocus raises and after that the RibbonButton dropdown menu appears. Everything OK.

After that, (3) I click on another RibbonButton. Again OnLostFocus raise, although - imho - it shouldn't.

So it goes on and on. After every action the TextBox keeps(or gets back, don't know) the focus and this causes the OnLostFocus-Handler to raise.

In WPF same code does not raise OnLostFocus again. Just one time, when it really lost focus.

Does anybody know, why this behaviour is that strange in Silverlight. What is really different to WPF, maybe I just have to set a property which default value ist different to WPF.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you mean TextBlock and not TextBox?

Comment: @RobSiklos Oh, damn, you're right. Of course TextBox.

Comment: From scratch - seems like it's usual `OnLostFocus` behavior. If you dont want to get this event right after each navigating from TextBox - you should extend it with some logic.

Comment: @anatoliiG, from the description, it doesn't seem like OP is ever purposely giving focus back to the TextBox. What I think the OP is saying is that once the TextBox get's (and then loses) focus ONCE, every action on any control after that is causing the LostFocus to run.

Comment: Calling myTextBox.Focus() in the LostFocus method causes an endless loop. In other words when it has lost focus and you call Focus to go back to it then it calls LostFocus again - even though it has not lost focus again. Now I'll have to put in some ugly hack to tell it "No you have not lost focus from the same control again - how is that even possible"

Answer (score 0):

Try using OnPreviewLostKeyboardFocus. OnLostFocus is for logical focus which you may lose for a variety reasons.

I don't know the reason for sure but I suspect that the problem you're seeing might be because the ribbon bar is in a FocusScope. When you put focus onto something inside of a focus scope then what you end up with can seem like focus bouncing around some. I'm not certain of this answer, focus is very complicated in WPF. Submitting some code samples might help.